# How to save images downloaded with icrawler GoogleImageCrawler to sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Help, I don't understand how to add images downloaded with icrawler GoogleImageCrawler to sqlite table.

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler
import sqlite3

database = sqlite3.connect("parserwoman.db")
sql = database.cursor()
table_name = 'photos'
sql_db = 'create table if not exists ' + table_name
sql.execute(f"{sql_db}(title text primary key not null, catphoto BLOB NOT NULL)")


def get_photo(keywords: str):
    filters = dict(size='large', type='photo')
    google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir': r"C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\photo"})
    google_crawler.crawl(keyword=keywords, max_num=1, min_size=(1024, 1024), max_size=None, filters=filters, file_idx_offset='auto')


titles = [
    'Abyssinian',
    'American Bobtail',
    'Himalayan'
]


for element in titles:
    get_photo(element)
    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (title, catphoto) VALUES (?, ?)", [element, get_photo(element)])
    database.commit()
```

I did not find any adequate solution

Comment: `getphoto` needs to return something. Either the location of the image, an Image object, etc.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this. Can you advise me?

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in `catphoto`?

Comment: i want to save the path to the downloaded file

Comment: I have given a sample answer. You can follow that and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the path where the image is saved, you need to return the file path to the saved image from `get_photo` function. Currently, return type of `get_photo` is `None`, so your database will not store anything in the field of `catphoto`. From what I saw, `icrawler` saves images in the format of `000001`, `000002`, etc. in the directory given by default.
You can do the following for example:

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler
import sqlite3

database = sqlite3.connect("parserwoman.db")
sql = database.cursor()
table_name = 'photos'
sql_db = 'create table if not exists ' + table_name
sql.execute(f"{sql_db}(title text primary key not null, catphoto BLOB NOT NULL)")


def get_photo(keywords: str, index:int):
    filters = dict(size='large', type='photo')
    google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir': r"C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\photo"})
    google_crawler.crawl(keyword=keywords, max_num=1, min_size=(1024, 1024), max_size=None, filters=filters, file_idx_offset='auto')
    return f"C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\photo\\{index:06}"


titles = [
    'Abyssinian',
    'American Bobtail',
    'Himalayan'
]

num_img = 1
for element in titles:
    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (title, catphoto) VALUES (?, ?)", [element, get_photo(element, num_img)])
    database.commit()
    num_img += 1
```

P.S. There is no reason to call `get_photo` twice for a single element, so I removed it. Hope this helps.